# Get cookie of a domain by another domain

Tags: session, cookies

Basically, I have a forum on domain abc.com and another one on xyz.com. When user login to abc.com and access to xyz.com. I want that xyz.com can read cookie of abc.com for further requests. So how can client side can read cookie of another domain? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web page rendered from one domain cannot read the cookies of another domain. This is by design and is for privacy purposes.

If you absolutely need the value, you will need to add a page to abc.com that reads the cookie and redirects to xyz.com, passing the cookie value as a querystring or form parameter. From that point, xyz.com can read the value from the request and set a cookie or otherwise provide the value to the page.

If you don't have access to xyz.com's code base, you will need to find a design that does not require the cookie to be shared.

Comment: So I need to add a new page that read cookies to abc.com and make a request containning cookie value to xyz.com. Am i right? Can you please explain further to me

Comment: Yes, you got it. Which part is troubling you?

Comment: is there any other ways to do the same thing like that since I prefer not to modify abc.com.

Comment: You can't get anything from abc.com unless abc.com is programmed to give it to you. It's by design. Imagine if any web site could grab your Facebook.com cookies and impersonate you! Definitely not possible.

Comment: How about telling abc.com that xyz.com is trusted? Is it possible?

Comment: @achilles. No. Trust is not the issue. A browser will not bother to submit a cookie with a page request unless the page and the cookie are located in the same domain. So the cookie simply isn't there for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as cross domain cookies. Due to security reasons cookies cannot be shared between two different domains. It is still possible for sub-domains like a.xyz.com and b.xyz.com but not for xyz.com and abc.com.